# Regarding Multiple Tab-Class

Tags: java

I've problem regarding GUI with one Menu and one Order Class.

I've created a variable to store how many items have been selected in the Menu Class.

```
private int totalSelected;
```

The var totalSelected is live updated. It can be changed anytime depending on `actionPerformed()` function.(Exp: `totalSelected` will add up all the selected items)

In the Order Class, how can I access to the live update variable totalSelected in order to retrieve the live update value? When I invoke `getTotalSelected()` function inside the Menu Class, I will only obtain a 0 value.

Thanks for your help ^^!

---

Please allow me to specify my question clearer.

```
public class MenuTab extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel display;
    private int totalSelected;
    public MenuTab()
    {
    ....
    }
}

public getTotalSelected(){
    return totalSelected;
}

private class SelectedListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed()
    {
       .......
       //Assume that totalSelected has been updated!
       display = new JLabel("Total: " + totalSelected);
       // OK to display totalSelected live value here.
    }

}

// A new class is the confirmation of order
public class OrderConfirmedTab extends JPanel{

private JLabel displayTotal;
private MenuTab order = new MenuTab();

public OrderConfirmedTab()
{
 ......
     int totalSelected = order.getTotalSelected();
     displayTotal = new JLabel("Total: " + totalSelected);
     // Problem to display totalSelected live value here.
     // Will obtain 0;
     // How can I obtain the live updated value from class MenuTab? Thanks!
}

}
```

Comment: Is there an `Order` instance as a member of the `Menu` class?  Also, can you show more code please?

Comment: Hi strager! Thanks for your reply! I'd edited my post to specify my problem clearer! Would you please take a look to see whether you can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code right, you need to make your variable be `private static int totalSelected;` You need to make it static so that it stays the same for all instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PropertyChangeListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) and [PropertyChangeSupport](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) mechanisms to dispatch an event when the value is updated and to be notified when the variable has changed. Your JLabel is not going to update on its own; even if you were to use an object  other than a primitive (note that primitives are merely values, while objects are actually implicit pointers); you will need to update your JLabel when the variable changes, since the JLabel simply stores  a string, not a reference to the variables from which the string was constructed.

This is the concept of model-view-controller; your variable should be in some sort of class or classes that represent the model (the information) and which allow changes to be observed via property change events. Your view classes should simply provide display logic and no business or application-specific logic. It is the controller in which your application logic should reside; your controller should register for events on the model, and it should update the view whenever the model has changed, and it should likewise update the model when the view dispatches events that should result in the model being changed.

Comment: Ya! I just realized that my JLabel will not update the value automatically. So how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @Christine, you need to fire a property change event whenever the value is updated. The class with the JLabel needs to register itself with the class in which the variable is located, and when it receives a property change event, it needs to update the JLabel accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your not updating the `private int totalSelected;` variable when a user makes a selection, so it is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Ya! I just realized that my JLabel
>   will not update the value
>   automatically. So how can I fix it?
>   Thanks! – Christine

If I understand you correctly you have two GUIs where changes in one (the MenuTab) will update the other (OrderConfirmedTab) in real time?

If so, you will need to increase the coupling between the two objects. If MenuTab has a reference back to OrderConfirmedTab then it can call methods to update the value as it changes.

For example, pass OrderConfirmedTab into MenuTabs constructor

```
MenuTab mt = new MenuTab(this); // from within OrderConfirmTabs costructor
```

Then when MenuTab has an actionPerformed event it can call back to OrderConfirmTab

```
orderConfirmTab.setTotalSelected(totalSelected); // you have to create this method in OrderConfirmTab
```

I hope this helps a little